# InnoSetup: search for a file and get the path

Tags: inno-setup, autocad-plugin

I need to get the path of autocad because I have to edit a text inside it (acad.lsp). For now I have to make n versions for every autocad:

```
'C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2009\Support\acad.lsp'
'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\Support\acad.lsp'
'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\Support\acad.lsp'
```

and so on.

Any Idea?
Thanks
Dennis

Comment: Since you can install AutoCAD in any folder on any drive, you would have to scan all drives deeply. That would take ages. Better will be find the installed version in registry and get the directories from there. I don't know about their hierarchy though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I've found tha @TLama: [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Detecting_Autocad_current_version_and_path) need to convert it maybe

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have more than one version installed side by side, but if so, then that script would not be much helpful because it reads only one version, the one that is pointed in the root `..\AutoCAD` key under the `CurVer` value. If side by side installation is allowed, then you will need to find all of them, that is iterate through the `..\AutoCAD\<?>` where `<?>` is some version identifier (that I don't know).

Comment: In my office I have two version installed (2009 and 2015) but usual people have only one. I saw another add on find all the version installed and asking for witch one you want to install the add-on

Comment: That's the next step, offering the users a selectable list of versions they want to install the add-on to. This [article](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Reinitiating-the-Secondary-Installer-for-AutoCAD.html) refers to some registry keys with a not well described pattern. You can iterate the registry keys and filter only those matching some pattern (like the mentioned subkeys `Rxx.x`). The problem is that I don't know the key structure as well as I don't know the value to be read.

Comment: maybe that can help?
[link](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/08/registry-values-for-productid-and-localeid-for-autocad.html)

Comment: and this is my home situation [link](https://db.tt/Rqn8qjmb)

Comment: We are closer to the pattern. But I still don't know from where to get the path (in which value). Just for fun, does [this script](http://pastebin.com/sKgpJGPi) show you the path (it queries the MSI API, but it relies on product codes which we would need to find; I've read the used one from your screenshot).

Comment: yeah, it works! [link](http://i.imgur.com/5CJ4TrN.png) sorry for late, I was having lunch :)

Comment: No problem :) What's the problem is that we don't know if all the versions 2016 have just this same product code (for all language IDs and sub-versions). This way would be the cleanest I'd say, but this bit of information is missing.

Comment: I think all 2016 are 20.1, 2015 20.0 and look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\Rxx.x\ACAD-XXXX:XXX\AcadLocation):

```
[..]
var
  Releases: TArrayOfString;
  I: Integer;
  Release: String;
  SubVersions: TArrayOfString;
  SubVersionsIndex: Integer;
  SubVersion: String;
begin
  if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\', Releases) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Releases) - 1 do
    begin
      Release := Releases[I];
      if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\' + Release + '\', SubVersions) then
        begin
          for SubVersionsIndex := 0 to GetArrayLength(SubVersions) - 1 do
          begin
            SubVersion := SubVersions[SubVersionsIndex];
            if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\' + Release + '\' + SubVersion, 'AcadLocation', AcadLocation) then
            begin
            [..]
```